# Get the hours between 9AM-5PM between two dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables with the below structure.

### Task Table

[image]

### Task Time Table

[image]

I want to get the time between `start_date_time` and `end_date_time` in days, hours and minutes. The time between 9AM-5PM is working hours and should only be considered for calculation. For example if `start_date_time` is `2019-03-25 09:00:00` and `end_date_time` is `2019-03-26 17:00:00` the calculated time will be 2 days. If `end_date_time` is  `2019-03-26 12:00:00` then the calculated time will be 1 day 3 hours. The same task can have multiple time entries and total time should be calculated. I have tried with below query to get the time, but it gives total hours. I only want hours between 9 AM and 5 PM. [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/szZvknZuxR86ntPwS5jPSj/0)

```
SELECT t.task_name, sum(time_to_sec(timediff(end_date_time, start_date_time )) / 3600) FROM `task_time` tt left join task t on tt.task_id=t.task_id
group by tt.task_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to deal with this is to compute the days and hours separately, and then just count a day as 8 hours. Something like this:

```
SELECT t.task_name, 
       SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, DATE(start_date_time), DATE(end_date_time)) * 8 +
           TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, TIME(start_date_time), TIME(end_date_time)) / 60) AS task_time
FROM task t
JOIN task_time tt ON tt.task_id = t.task_id
GROUP BY t.task_name
```

Output (for my demo data)

```
task_name   task_time
task1       16
task2       11
task3       4
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hsjrKTW4K3cvxMfoUi84ES/1)

**Update**

This query will allow for start and end times to be outside 9AM-5PM while only counting hours between 9AM and 5PM as working hours. It works by forcing the start and end times into the 9AM-5PM range by using `GREATEST` and `LEAST`:

```
SELECT t.task_name, 
       SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, start_date, end_date) * 8 +
           TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, TIME(start_time), TIME(end_time)) / 60) AS task_time
FROM task t
JOIN (SELECT task_id,
             DATE(start_date_time) AS start_date,
             DATE(end_date_time) AS end_date,
             GREATEST('09:00', LEAST('17:00', TIME(start_date_time))) AS start_time,
             GREATEST('09:00', LEAST('17:00', TIME(end_date_time))) AS end_time
      FROM task_time) tt ON tt.task_id = t.task_id
GROUP BY t.task_name
```

[Updated demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hsjrKTW4K3cvxMfoUi84ES/2)

**Update 2**

This query returns the time as days, hours and minutes instead of just hours.

```
SELECT t.task_name,
       days + FLOOR(minutes / 480) AS days,
       CASE WHEN minutes < 0 THEN 8 + FLOOR(minutes % 480 / 60)
            ELSE FLOOR(minutes % 480 / 60)
            END AS hours,
       CASE WHEN minutes < 0 THEN (60 + (minutes % 60)) % 60
            ELSE minutes % 60
            END AS minutes
FROM (SELECT t.task_name, 
             SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, start_date, end_date)) AS days,
             SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, TIME(start_time), TIME(end_time))) AS minutes
      FROM task t
      JOIN (SELECT task_id,
                   DATE(start_date_time) AS start_date,
                   DATE(end_date_time) AS end_date,
                   GREATEST('09:00', LEAST('17:00', TIME(start_date_time))) AS start_time,
                   GREATEST('09:00', LEAST('17:00', TIME(end_date_time))) AS end_time
            FROM task_time) tt ON tt.task_id = t.task_id
      GROUP BY t.task_name) t
```

[Updated demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hsjrKTW4K3cvxMfoUi84ES/4)

Comment: The important thing is that we should only consider the time between 9AM-5PM.

Comment: @user1690835 as long as the start and end times are between 9AM and 5PM this will do that. Is it possible that they might not be?

Comment: It may not be. I have added the DB Fiddle in the question.

Comment: If a user works overtime, it won't be considered. If he takes 9AM-8PM to complete a task only 9AM-5PM will be considered. I know it is a complicated query, that is why I asked for help.

Comment: @user1690835 no worries, just wanted to be sure. See my edit.

Comment: Great! you saved the day. Is there a way to avoid Saturdays and Sundays as well?

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is almost correct. My actual question is to get the result in days, hours and mins.

Comment: @user1690835 3rd time lucky? I think the weekend issue is hard enough to merit another question.

Comment: Unfortunately third one is not giving correct result. DB Fiddle at https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/szZvknZuxR86ntPwS5jPSj/1

Comment: @user1690835 sorry about that. I forgot to consider multiple start/end times for each task. I think I've got it this time.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks.